# Buffered op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer, cadence

I am trying to design the following CMOS circuit of an op-amp with a buffer using Cadence software.

In the buffer circuit, I need to add bias. What kind of biasing is needed for this circuit? Idc or Vdc? and where to place them? 
http://web.engr.uky.edu/~elias/projects/07.pdf
[image]

Comment: Why have multiple buffer stages - surely you only need one.

Comment: Also,your input diff pair looks strange. Like ibe us nmos and the other is pmos. Or maybe one has its S D pins switched.